# Extension methods don't work on subclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Apparently, extension methods don't work on subclasses, or is it just me?

```
private class Parent
{        
}

private class Child
{
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Method(this Parent parent)
    {
    }
}

//Test code
var p = new Parent();
p.Method();            // <--- compiler like
var c = new Child();
c.Method();            // <--- compiler no like
```

**UPDATE**

There is a typo in this question (which I'm leaving so that the rest makes sense) - I forgot to make `Child` inherit from `Parent`.

As it happens, my real problem was that I didn't have the appropriate `using` statement.

*(Unfortunately, I can't delete, as too many upvotes on answer.)*

Comment: I am guessing that Child is supposed to inherit Parent? (ok, just a few seconds late there :o) )

Answer (score 8):

This should work just fine (LINQ extensions are built on top of `IEnumerable<T>`, and they work on `List<T>` et al.).  The issue is that `Child` does not inherit from `Parent` in your example.

Comment: Yes. Benjoi, can we assume a typo or is this the answer?

Comment: OK, my bad :( Typo indeed. The thing is, this was demo code to try and reproduce the problem for the question's sake. But in the real code, it doesn't work. *Back to the coalface...*  (Should I just delete the question?)

Comment: @Benjol: Yes, if you can. Feel free to ask a new question though, with an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Benjol, complier checks extension methods only in types available in current scope - check your references and namespaces (using directives). Perhaps type implementing extension method is simply not in reference scope where you want to use it.

Comment: @Henk, @Marc, I'd forgotten the `using` - or rather, I'd already included it in one source file, and with intervening interruptions I'd confused which file...